# why layout gets changed when width of block element is defined in % or in px

Tags: css, css-float

I have written very simple HTML;

```
<div style="float:left;width:100px;background-color:red">RED</div>
<div style="background-color:blue">BLUE</div>
```

If I don't set width of second DIV or set it in % then both DIVs come in single line. Whereas, if I give width in *px*, it comes in second line.

I din't find any reference elaborating this behavior. I checked it with chrome and firefox both.

Demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux6JU/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `div` is a `block` level element with a width of 100%.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh5hD/) - See without setting a width, or floating them, they appear on new lines, taking up 100%.

By floating the first element, you are taking it out of the normal flow of the document, therefore it no long fully acts as a `block` level element. Thus, if you don't set a width on the second one, it is actually overlapping the first one.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTwyu/) - first `div` has a transprent background to demonstrate this.

Even if you do set a width on both `divs` (assuming they aren't floated), they are still `block` level elements, appearing on separate lines. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/urcds/)

Comment: my question is why it behaves different when I set width in % and in px. When I set it in %, both DIV comes in single line. Whereas when I take it in px they appears in separate line. refer [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTwyu/1/)

Comment: @articlestack You have a type in that jsFiddle.. it's `width:50%`.

Comment: specify any width in % for second DIV, you'll get both DIVs in same line. Specify any width in px for second DIV, you'll get both DIVs in separate line

Comment: I think its because by inline stylesheet. I have attached a demo link in question. Plz have a look

Comment: @articlestack Simply because the text is wrapping. Look at what happens if you add `white-space:nowrap;`.. http://jsfiddle.net/azvGt/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39609/discussion-between-articlestack-and-joshc)